# Adding a 'Thank You' popup after I click 'Submit' on Bootstrap Modal form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to add a 'Thank you for you submission' popup to my bootstrap modal when someone clicks 'Submit' on the form.

**The problem is that when the 'Submit' button gets clicked on a bootstrap modal form, the entire page gets refreshed.**

How do I prevent the modal from refreshing the entire page so I can successfully display a popup after 'Submit' has been clicked?

Comment: Can you submit your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listen to the form submission event

```
$('form').submit(function (e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    setTimeout(function () {
        form.submit();
    }, 10000); // in milliseconds
    $("<p>thank you for your submittion</p>").appendTo("body");
});
```

or try this:

```
$("#submission_button").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();//prevent default action 

});
```

Comment: The second one worked for me! Thanks!